# Codename one Build error, unable to build in IOS app

Tags: ios, codenameone

I have a codename one app that is working normally in android and IOS.
The 2nd app, works normally in android build, but always displays an error in Ios build, after sending to server. I am removing builds, refreshing libs files, but each time, it shows an error after the build, only in the app that is not working.
Most recent error:

```
  === BUILD TARGET MyApplication OF PROJECT MyApplication WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===

    Check dependencies
    Code Signing Error: Provisioning profile "College App IOS_DEVELOPMENT Profile" doesn't include the com.apple.developer.icloud-services entitlement.
    warning: skipping file '/var/folders/p_/xlvwhg4101z8r81_nl13cds80000gn/T/build1084661638350343875xxx/dist/MyApplication-src/MyApplication-Prefix.pch' (unexpected file type 'sourcecode.c.objc.preprocessed' in Frameworks & Libraries build phase)
    warning: skipping file '/var/folders/p_/xlvwhg4101z8r81_nl13cds80000gn/T/build1084661638350343875xxx/dist/MyApplication-src/MyApplication-Info.plist' (unexpected file type 'text.plist.xml' in Frameworks & Libraries build phase)
    Warning: The Link Binary With Libraries build phase contains this target's Info.plist file 'MyApplication-src/MyApplication-Info.plist'.
    Code Signing Error: Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 11.2'

 === BUILD TARGET MyApplication OF PROJECT MyApplication WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===
Check dependencies
Code Signing Error: Provisioning profile "College App IOS_DEVELOPMENT Profile" doesn't include the com.apple.developer.icloud-services entitlement.
warning: skipping file '/var/folders/p_/xlvwhg4101z8r81_nl13cds80000gn/T/build6819108292745406701xxx/dist/MyApplication-src/MyApplication-Prefix.pch' (unexpected file type 'sourcecode.c.objc.preprocessed' in Frameworks & Libraries build phase)
warning: skipping file '/var/folders/p_/xlvwhg4101z8r81_nl13cds80000gn/T/build6819108292745406701xxx/dist/MyApplication-src/MyApplication-Info.plist' (unexpected file type 'text.plist.xml' in Frameworks & Libraries build phase)
Warning: The Link Binary With Libraries build phase contains this target's Info.plist file 'MyApplication-src/MyApplication-Info.plist'.
Code Signing Error: Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 11.2'

** ARCHIVE FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Check dependencies
(1 failure)
Process return code is 65
Failed xcodebuild step
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you edit the provisioning to include iCloud?

I'm assuming you included the file chooser cn1lib where [this sentence exists](https://github.com/shannah/cn1-filechooser):

> If deploying to iOS, you'll need to make sure that your App ID includes iCloud support. (Currently it should not be associated with any iCloud containers).

You can generate iOS provisioning here: https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/profile/

[image]

It means you need to generate a provisioning profile from Apples provisioning profile website

Comment: I have already done it, and the is still not working, despite the build working on the other project normally. Please also check the update of the error which I pasted above.

Comment: Did you download and replace the provisioning file in the project?

Comment: I solved it with resetting the build hints. Thank you.